# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'str'

Tags: python, keras, model

I have built a sequential model with a customized f1 score metric. I pass this during the compilation of my model and then save it in `*.hdf5` format. Whenever I load the model for testing purposes using the `custom_objects` attribute

`model = load_model('app/model/test_model.hdf5', custom_objects={'f1':f1})`

Keras throws the following error

> ```
> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'str'
> ```

Note: No errors are shown if I don't include the f1 metric during compilation, and the testing process works well.

**Train method**

```
from metrics import f1

...

# GRU with glove embeddings and two dense layers
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                    100,
                    weights=[embedding_matrix],
                    input_length=max_len,
                    trainable=False))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.3))
model.add(GRU(100, dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.3, return_sequences=True))
model.add(GRU(100, dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.3))

model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.8))

model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.8))

model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc', f1])

# Fit the model with early stopping callback
earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=3, verbose=0, mode='auto')
model.fit(xtrain_pad, y=ytrain_enc, batch_size=512, epochs=100, 
        verbose=1, validation_data=(xvalid_pad, yvalid_enc), callbacks=[earlystop])

model.save('app/model/test_model.hdf5')
```

**Test method**

```
from metrics import f1

...

model = load_model('app/model/test_model.hdf5', custom_objects={'f1':f1}) 
print(model.summary())

model.evaluate(xtest_pad, ytest_enc) # <-- error happens
```

**Custom f1 metric**

```
from keras import backend as K

def f1(y_true, y_pred):
    def recall(y_true, y_pred):
        """Recall metric.

        Only computes a batch-wise average of recall.

        Computes the recall, a metric for multi-label classification of
        how many relevant items are selected.
        """
        true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
        possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
        recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
        return recall

    def precision(y_true, y_pred):
        """Precision metric.

        Only computes a batch-wise average of precision.

        Computes the precision, a metric for multi-label classification of
        how many selected items are relevant.
        """
        true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
        predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
        precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
        return precision 
    
    precision = precision(y_true, y_pred)
    recall = recall(y_true, y_pred)
    return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon()))
```

**EDIT**

**test**

The preprocessed data used for evaluating the model

```
normalized_dataset = pd.read_pickle(DATA['preprocessed_test_path'])

lbl_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
y = lbl_enc.fit_transform(normalized_dataset.label.values)

xtest = normalized_dataset.preprocessed_tweets.values
ytest_enc = np_utils.to_categorical(y)

token = text.Tokenizer(num_words=None)
max_len = 70

token.fit_on_texts(list(xtest))
xtest_seq = token.texts_to_sequences(xtest)
xtest_pad = sequence.pad_sequences(xtest_seq, maxlen=max_len)
```

**EDIT2**

This is my full traceback that triggers the stated error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app/main.py", line 67, in <module>
    main()
  File "app/main.py", line 64, in main
    test(embedding_dict)
  File "/Users/justauser/Desktop/sentiment-analysis/app/test.py", line 50, in test
    model.evaluate(xtest_pad, ytest_enc)
  File "/Users/justauser/Desktop/sentiment-analysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1389, in evaluate
    tmp_logs = self.test_function(iterator)
  File "/Users/justauser/Desktop/sentiment-analysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/justauser/Desktop/sentiment-analysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 871, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/Users/justauser/Desktop/sentiment-analysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 725, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/Users/justauser/Desktop/sentiment-analysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2969, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/justauser/Desktop/sentiment-analysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3361, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/justauser/Desktop/sentiment-analysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3196, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "/Users/justauser/Desktop/sentiment-analysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 990, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/Users/justauser/Desktop/sentiment-analysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 634, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/justauser/Desktop/sentiment-analysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 977, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
TypeError: in user code:

    /Users/justauser/Desktop/sentiment-analysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1233 test_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /Users/justauser/Desktop/sentiment-analysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1224 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /Users/justauser/Desktop/sentiment-analysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /Users/justauser/Desktop/sentiment-analysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /Users/justauser/Desktop/sentiment-analysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /Users/justauser/Desktop/sentiment-analysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1219 run_step  **
        with ops.control_dependencies(_minimum_control_deps(outputs)):
    /Users/justauser/Desktop/sentiment-analysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:2793 _minimum_control_deps
        outputs = nest.flatten(outputs, expand_composites=True)
    /Users/justauser/Desktop/sentiment-analysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py:341 flatten
        return _pywrap_utils.Flatten(structure, expand_composites)

    TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'str'
```

Comment: `model.evaluate(xtest_pad, ytest_enc) # <-- error happens`  .. you do not show what `xtest_pad`, `ytest_pad` are. Print their type`s. Is one of them a funciton? Why?

Comment: @PatrickArtner output of the following command `print(type(xtest_pad), type(ytest_enc))` is  `<class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. The model works without the `custom_objects` attribute, so the type's shouldn't be a problem I'd say

Comment: always put full error mesage (strting a wod "Traceback") in question (not commet) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas sorry for that, I have edited the post again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After `model.load()` if you compile your model again with the custom metric then it should work.

Therefore, after loading your model from disk using

```
model = load_model('app/model/test_model.hdf5', custom_objects={'f1':f1})
```

Make sure to compile it with the metrics of interest

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc', f1])
```

Comment: Isn't this going to reset the optimizer state?

Comment: I think it does reset the optimizer's state, which is a problem if you want to do checkpointing, and train afterwards (not just evaluate). See [this colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1z7I5J-GgDGV71kkTV3Wgog4iPSOnF0oF?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3):

As @Zaccharie Ramzi pointed out, the accepted answer is not suitable if you want to load model to resume training, as the compiling step will reset the optimizer state (this is anyway fine if you want only to evaluate or test the model). If you want to load the model to resume training you can workaround this issue recompiling the loaded model using the output of the load:

```
model = load_model('app/model/test_model.hdf5', custom_objects={'f1':f1}) 
model.compile(loss=model.loss, optimizer=model.optimizer, metrics=['acc', f1])
```

As a reference see the [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45903) where this solution was posted first.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem!

The score of the in-memory model and the score on `load_model` is the same.

```
scores = model.evaluate(X, y, verbose=2, batch_size = batch_size)
```